# Issue in extracting hyperlinks in Pdf using iTextsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, annotations, itext

I'm using iTextSharp to extract all the hyperlinks in a PDF file.

Below is my code and it is working fine with all PDF but except the one which I have enclosed with this question.

While extracting this PDF it shows Links as count=0 and Annots as null.

How do I get these hyperlinks?

```
var Links= pdfReader.GetLinks(PageNo); // return count=0
```

or

```
PdfDictionary PageDictionary = pdfReader.GetPageN(PageNo);
PdfArray Annots = PageDictionary.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS); // returns null
```

Comment: i could not upload the sample pdf you can download this from this link http://support.aspentech.com/supportpublictrain/AspenTech%20Course%20Catalog%2001_2012.pdf

Comment: Any solution? I am having the same issue... it works on many, but doesn't seem to always find annotations.

Comment: i m facing same issue any solution for this...asap